# How to stop jquery $.Deferred().pipe animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, deferred

I'm creating animations on multiple objects that have to be executed one after another. For this I use construction such as this:

```
var deferredAnimations = $.Deferred();
deferredAnimations.pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " h1 span.text").unbind()
        .typist({
            cursor: true,
            speed: 12,
            text: 'Hello'
        }).typistStop().delay(2000);
}).
pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " h2").unbind()
        .typist({
            cursor: true,
            speed: 12,
            text: 'world'
        }).typistStop().delay(3000);
}).
pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " h2").
        selectText().
        delay(1000);
}).pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " #drop-in-tool").show().addClass("magictime slideUpRetourn").delay(1000);
}).pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " h2").
        removeClass("fira-sans").
        addClass("droid-serif green italic").
        delay(1000);
}).pipe(function() {
    $("#" + page + " #drop-in-tool").fadeOut("slow");
    return $("#" + page + " h1").
        selectText().
        delay(1000);
}).pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " h1").
        removeClass("work-sans bold").
        addClass("roboto-condensed upper").
        delay(1500);
}).pipe(function() {
    deselectText();
    $("#" + page + " .pop-lines").css("left", $("#" + page).find("h1 .text").offset().left - 20);
    $("#" + page + " h1").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#" + page + " h2").fadeOut("slow");
    return animatePageBackground(page);
}).pipe(function() {
    $("#" + page + " h1").show().addClass("magictime slideLeftRetourn");
    return $("#" + page + " h2").show().addClass("magictime slideRightRetourn").delay(1000);
})
.pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " .pop-line1").css("visibility", "visible").addClass("magictime swashIn").delay(50);
}).pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " .pop-line2").css("visibility", "visible").addClass("magictime swashIn").delay(50);
}).pipe(function() {
    return $("#" + page + " .pop-line3").css("visibility", "visible").addClass("magictime swashIn").delay(50);
}).pipe(function() {
    return animatePageFooter(page);
});

deferredAnimations.resolve();


//page background animate
function animatePageBackground(page) {
    return $("#" + page).promise().pipe(function() {
        $("#" + page + " .page-grid").fadeOut();
        return $("#" + page + " h1").animate({"color":"#ffffff"}, 1000).delay(1000);
    }).pipe(function() {
        $("#" + page + " .page-header").animate({"color":"#ffffff"}, 2000);
        return $("#" + page + " .page-back").fadeIn(2000).delay(1000);
    });
}

//page footer animations
function animatePageFooter(page) {
    $("#" + page).promise().pipe(function() {
        return $("#" + page + " .profile-icon").show().addClass("magictime slideDownRetourn").delay(500);
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $("#" + page + " .profile-name").show().addClass("magictime slideDownRetourn").delay(500);
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $("#" + page + " .icons").show().addClass("magictime slideDownRetourn").delay(500);
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $("#" + page + " .link").show().addClass("magictime slideDownRetourn").delay(500);
    }).pipe(function() {
        return $("#" + page + " .back-btn").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

but I want to stop all the animations when I click a button and deferredAnimations.reject() doesn't work in this case because as I understand pipe creates new Deferred.

Is there a way to stop animations in pipe list.
Are there any better solution for sequential animations on multiple objects that can be interrupted?

Thanks.

Comment: [jQuery queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: why are using pipe you can use then or done, it will be easy for you to use.

Comment: @JhonCarpenter probably because of jQuery version. There was a version or two where .then was nothing more than a success/failure handler and .pipe was required to chain.

Comment: @SvetlinStoev, please edit your question with code that *fully* represents your issue.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I've pasted the whole code. Sorry that I have  not pasted it  when posted the question, but I thought it's too big to be pasted here. Thanks.

Comment: @SvetlinStoev, there an issue to solve before trying to install a "stop" mechanism. First you need to write the promise chain such that it actually works as you want. Currently, most of the stages don't return promises, meaning the next stage will start immediately. As currently written, the `.delay()` commands will indeed introduce some delay but not in the way you think.